# Running a single kafka s3 sink connector in standalone vs distributed mode

Tags: apache-kafka, apache-kafka-connect

I have a kafka topic "mytopic" with 10 partitions and want to use [S3 sink connector](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/kafka-connect-s3/index.html) to sink records to an S3 bucket. For scaling purposes it should be running on multiple nodes to write partitions data in parallel to the same S3 bucket.

In Kafka connect [user guide](https://docs.confluent.io/current/connect/userguide.html) and actually many other blogs/tutorials it's recommended to run workers in distributed mode instead of standalone to achieve better scalability and fault tolerance:

> ... distributed mode is more flexible in terms of scalability and offers the added advantage of a highly available service to minimize downtime.

I want to figure out which mode to choose for my use case: having one logical connector running on multiple nodes in parallel. My understanding is following:

1. If I run in distributed mode, I will end up having only 1 worker processing all the partitions, since it's considered one connector task.
2. Instead I should run in standalone mode in multiple nodes. In that case I will have a consumer group and achieve parallel processing of partitions.
3. In above described standalone scenario I will actually have fault tolerance: if one instance dies, the consumer group will rebalance and other standalone workers will handle the freed partitions.

Is my understaning correct or am I missing something?

Unfortunately I couldn't find much information on this topic other than [this google groups discussion](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/confluent-platform/euovCY4wic0), where the author came to the same conclusion as I did.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In theory, that might work, but you'll end up ssh-ing to multiple machines, having basically the same config files, and just not using the `connect-distributed` command instead of `connect-standalone`.

You're missing the part about Connect server task rebalancing, though, which communicates over the Connect server REST ports

The underlying task code is all the same, only the entrypoint and offset storage are different. So, why not just use distributed if you have multiple machines?

Comment: What about my first point? Will there be any parallel processing or will I have only 1 worker doing all the job?

Comment: If you run multiple servers, then the tasks are distributed among them. It works no differently than a regular Consumer group

Answer (score 1):

You don't need to run, multiple instances of standalone processes, the Kafka workers are taking care of distributing the tasks, rebalancing, offset management under the distributed mode, you need to specify the same group id ...